# Crear estructura con flexbox

Tags: html, css3, responsive, flexbox, css-grid-layout

El `<body>` contiene una columna de tres cuadros o filas(`<header>`, `<main>`
y `<footer>`).

`<main>` contiene una fila de 2 cuadros o columnas(`<article>` y `<aside>`), por lo que debe `<article>` ocupar ⅔ del ancho de la página y `<aside>` ⅓; el header contiene tres `<li>` que deben ir al lado derecho. todo usando flexbox css

Comment: no se si te acabe de entender bien , si pudieras poner img o algo similar seria mejor, igualmente alguna solución seria crear celdas de mas y ocultarlas o también podrías hacer que una celda ocupe 3 , con rowspan ocuparías la cantidad a lo alto y con colspan lo harías a lo largo, no se si es solución a tu pregunta...

Comment: Si gracias, @DavidGonzalo tu rspuesta fue de ayuda